# Why does splitting on a period need double back-slashes?

Tags: java, split

I have a `String` called `filename`:

```
filename = "z_cams_c_ecmf_20170217000000_prod_fc_pl_015_aermr04.nc";
```

When I try to split the `filename` to get the variable name `aermr04.nc`, I tried the following:

```
String varibleName = filename.split("_")[9].split(".")[0];
```

The above line of code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Why?

I can get it tow work by using:

```
String varibleName = filename.split("_")[9].split("\\.")[0];
```

However, it seems rather silly that I have to fiddle around with such trivial tasks...

Any idea why the 2nd example works? What is the reasoning behind such syntax?

Comment: Because the period `.`, in a regex, means "any character". So for a literal period, it needs to be escaped (i.e. preceded by a backslash). But since the backslash '\' in a string needs to be escaped, it becomes `"\\."`.

Comment: @yshavit Ha, it is. Let me wok on that :)

Comment: Note that you can do this without regex or creating all the unnecessary strings and arrays, using `String varibleName = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('_'), filename.lastIndexOf('.'))` (assuming those really are the last `_` and `.` in your string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `.split()` is treated as a regular expression. `"."` as a regex matches everything.

To match a period, you need to escape the `"."` regex as `"\\."`

Comment: Note that using code formatting shows up your double backslashes.